# How to automatically stop Apache when login into a user session

Tags: scripts, apache2, network-manager, administrator

I want to develop a web service and need Apache to turn off when logged on a user account. To activate it when only when I'm developing.

I use a **hotspot** to try the web service via WiFi

I've tried to add a script on **startup applications**:

```
systemctl stop apache
```

But it is not working to **stop apache** on login,

Comment: have you tried to make a script on /etc/network/interfaces.d ? else if you need the network interface for other purposes, you could try putting this script on cron every second or so 'wget --spider http://site.example.com if [ "$?" != 0 ]; then
  scripttodisableapache
fi

Comment: @Cloaker "This is where you
       configure how your system is connected to the network." Is not a matter of how but While/When. Maybe it can be "how your system network management works"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First disable Apache Server

```
sudo systemctl disable apache2
```

Everytime you use the apache serve do the contraty

```
sudo systemctl start apache2
```

When finished do :

```
sudo systemctl stop apache2
```